# does google provide a wsdl or wadl

Tags: wsdl, google-sheets-api, wadl, blueprism

Currently was playing around with a robotic process application called Blue Prism and learned you can drop a URL link to a WSDL location to consume api calls. I tested using a free service and it worked great.

My question is in regards to Google Sheets API, a project has come up where this would be very usefull however I'm not able to locate or if one even exists (A WSDL or WADL) for the google sheets api.

If anyone could give me any direction on this that would be fantastic.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: There is no code involved. Im searching for the Web services description language or web application description language that describe the google sheets apis. Its essentially an XML file.

Comment: From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google docs can be automated using REST web services. You can find more information about google docs api at [google sheets API page.](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/)

BluePrism has an out-of-box tools to work with SOAP request with WSDL, but unfortunately it does not have out-of-box support for REST web services.

If you'd like to use API to interact with google docs, then you can do that, but you'll have to create your own code stages to do that.